# jQuery Radio Select Display Associated Fields

Tags: jquery

So I have a pretty basic form that I'm using radio buttons that I need to determine the fields that need to be displayed. If one is chosen then it displays a list of fields that are associated by class. If the other is chosen it should display those fields and the other ones should be hidden (this is where I'm getting a bit tripped up).

The form looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
 <input type="radio" value="Internal Form" name="training_event[registration]" id="training_event_registration_internal_form">
 <label for="training_event_registration_true">Internal Form</label>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="radio" value="External URL" name="training_event[registration]" id="training_event_registration_external_url">
     <label for="training_event_registration_false">External URL</label>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The other fields are wrapped in the following:

```
<div class="internal-form">
</div>
<div class="external_url">
</div>
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.internal-form).hide();
 $('.external_url').hide();
 $('#training_event_registration_internal_form').click(function (){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $('.internal-form').show();
  } else {
   $('.internal-form').empty();
   $('.internal-form').css("display", "none");
   $('.external_url').show();
  }
}
```

So the only thing that works properly here is the hide on both forms from the get go.

So how do I display the associated fields when one is selected and then switch when the other field is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues in your logic:

- You're missing a closing quote on `$('.internal-form)`
- `$(this).is(":checked")` will always be `true` as you just clicked on the radio to select it. You need to check the `val()` of the element instead.
- Hide `.internal-form` and `.external_url` in CSS instead of JS to avoid a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).
- Use the `change` event when dealing with checkbox and radio inputs, not `click`. This is for accessibility reasons.

Also, are you certain you need the `empty()` call in there? It wipes the content of the element, but you never replace it. In the example below I removed it, as it seemed to cause a problem instead of solve one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').change(function() {  
    if ($(this).val() == 'Internal Form') {
      $('.internal-form').show();
      $('.external_url').hide();
    } else {
      $('.internal-form').hide();
      $('.external_url').show();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.internal-form, .external_url {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="Internal Form" name="training_event[registration]" class="trigger">
    Internal Form
  </label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="External URL" name="training_event[registration]" class="trigger">
        External URL
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="internal-form">
  INTERNAL FORM
</div>
<div class="external_url">
  EXTERNAL URL
</div>
```

Note that the `label` elements now wrap each radio input, and as a result the `for` and `id` attributes are no longer necessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. hide the two result `div`s *internal-form* and *external_url* via CSS;
2. apply the jQuery `click` method to the `input`s with `type` *radio* and `name` *training_event[registration]* to toggle the visibility of the resulting `div`s.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:radio[name="training_event[registration]"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Internal Form') {
      $('.internal-form').show();
      $('.external_url').hide();
    } else {
      $('.internal-form').hide();
      $('.external_url').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.internal-form, .external_url {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="radio" value="Internal Form" name="training_event[registration]" id="training_event_registration_internal_form">
  <label for="training_event_registration_true">Internal Form</label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="radio" value="External URL" name="training_event[registration]" id="training_event_registration_external_url">
      <label for="training_event_registration_false">External URL</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="internal-form">.internal-form</div>
<div class="external_url">.external-url</div>
```